# Creating a df in pandas based off a Count > 1

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to create a new dataframe based on whether a value appears multiple times in a column.

```
Parcel      Permit     Town
123Q        ABC        BLD
1000        A45        BLD
9999        G5R        BLD
123Q        LK9        BLD
123Q        Q2W        BLD
```

So my goal would be to create a dataframe that pulls the parcel number 123Q.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Use  groupby.transform` to performance a [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df[df.groupby('Parcel').Parcel.transform('size')>1]
```

or [`GroupBy.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.filter.html)

```
df.groupby('Parcel').filter(lambda x: x.Parcel.size > 1)
```

---

**Output**

```
  Parcel Permit Town
0   123Q    ABC  BLD
3   123Q    LK9  BLD
4   123Q    Q2W  BLD
```

Answer (score 1):

This is [`DataFrame.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html), with argument `keep=False`, to keep all the duplicated rows.

```
df[df.duplicated('Parcel',keep=False)]

  Parcel Permit Town
0   123Q    ABC  BLD
3   123Q    LK9  BLD
4   123Q    Q2W  BLD
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is using `value_counts`, `map` and slice

```
df[df.Parcel.map(df.Parcel.value_counts() > 1)]

Out[1854]:
  Parcel Permit Town
0  123Q   ABC    BLD
3  123Q   LK9    BLD
4  123Q   Q2W    BLD
```